# Algorithm for Community deletion of questions

Tags: support, community-user, auto-delete

Is the algorithm for Community deletion of questions documented anywhere? I'm interested in both the SO and MSO algorithms, in case they are different.

If it matters, the trigger for this question is an innocuous, unanswered [question of mine from six months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947744/tests-for-rails-tutorial-chapter-10-exercise-7-micropost-character-countdown) ago that received it's first and only downvote recently and which I flagged (as an FYI only, not expecting any reversal) as likely being part of a small retaliatory downvote.